# How to resolve dependency to mule-module-multi-tx-ee?

Tags: maven, mule

When build a project it fails with a message "mule-module-multi-tx-ee".

The concrete error is:

> Could not find artifact
>   org.mule.modules:mule-module-multi-tx-ee:jar:3.3.2 in MuleRepository
>   (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/)

I have set up Mule to connect to the Enterprise repository, however in that repository at:
https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/org/mule/modules/

There are other modules but no "mule-module-multi-tx-ee". So how shall that work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository is a mirror: it populates lazily, on demand, so it's OK not to see the artifacts if you browse. When Maven requests them, they should show up.

I think the problem is that you have the `groupId` wrong: it should be `com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules` not `org.mule.modules`.

Comment: I think you are right, the issue is that dependency is wrong.

Comment: This is also described in their website at: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/Working+with+Maven